# Save AS excel file to specific location using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am have a code that picks some worksheets from workbook and creates a new file. but it saves the newly generated file at random location. I would like to save the new file at specific location.
Looking help and threads I have randomly used

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename
```

It gives me pop up window for "Save as" but it doesn't save the file in the location I have mentioned.  Can anyone please see my macro and help me.

here is my code.

```
Sub SaveMain()

Dim Flname As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("3").Range("N15").Value =   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations").Range("W23").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("3").Range("N16").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations").Range("W28").Value
'there are some more copy cells

Flname = "Pump Datasheet-" & InputBox("Save file as") & ".xls"
Sheets(Array("Cover", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")).Copy
newfilename = Flname
With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs newfilename, FileFormat:=50
Application.GetSaveAsFilename
.Close 0
End With
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 If ws.Name <> "Main Calc" Then
 ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End If

Next
Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this format:

```
saveAsFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fName, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If saveAsFileName <> "False" Then
    'Do something here
Else
    'Do something else here
End If
```

Comment: couldn't run it. Very new to macros.
what part should I replace as this code? 
Gave me error  Run time error '9'
subscription out of range

Answer (score 0):

`Flname = "C:\temp\Pump Datasheet-" & InputBox("Save file as") & ".xls"`

That will save your file as "Pump Datasheet-content from inputbox.xls" in `C:\temp`

Currently you don't specify a folder name, so Excel is just saving it in whatever its default save location is.

Comment: Can I set a location? I just want to Pop up save as window so can save wherever I want and just not always fixed path.

Comment: Sure - just grab the path from the user and append it in front of the file name you want to use:  `filepath = InputBox("Save file in location:")` will get the filepath, and then just do `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filepath & "\" & Flname, FileFormat:=50` (having set Flname to whatever filename you need, including the file type suffix)

Comment: gave me error. it says file path does not exist. 
i dont want the fix file path I want to save as to different location every time I produce it.

Comment: If you allow the user to specify a file path, you had better validate it to ensure that it does indeed exist before you try to save to it.  You can use `FSO.FolderExists` on a folder path to verify if it exists or not.  What file path are you passing in via the InputBox for example?  Have you checked it DOES exist?